# Reg:how to access the apis's of USB libaries in android

Tags: libusb

I am using android 2.2 version. I want to use the USB related API's in android application. but in android 2.2 version is not having the API's in the applicaition framework layer.It is available in 3.1 and newer version of android.

but in android source code i have seen libraries for USB (API 's in the format of .c and .h file).whether i can able to access the api in the application layer of the android. I want to use the USB device for example, Test CDC class.

For example : if i want to initalize the USB then i can able to call the USB_init() function which is in the USB.c.. Is this possible???? any one please help me.......

Regards
Ram